# Autoclick on tinymce

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a web app I'm using tinymce and I have to auto click a button.
This is the code:

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    theme: "modern",
    skin: "light",
    resize: false,
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.addButton('mybutton', {
            title : 'My button',
            image : 'quill.png',
            onclick : function() {
                $scope.openDialog();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

How can I call the 'onclick' method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I had this same issue with tinyMCE 4, and couldn't get any of the solutions above to work. This worked for me:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.buttons.charmap.onclick();
```

So for example I was trying to create a custom menu in a plugin that included some built in commands:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor) {

    editor.addButton('mymenu', {
        type: 'menubutton',
        text: 'Insert',
        icon: false,
        menu: [
            {
                text: 'Special Character',
                icon: 'charmap',
                onclick: function() { editor.buttons.charmap.onclick(); }
            }
        ]
    });

});
```